# How to insert newline without indent in the same line in YAML mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, yaml, indentation, auto-indent

I have this function attach to enter:

```
(defun new-line-and-indent-fix ()
  (interactive)
  (newline)
  (indent-for-tab-command))
```

and in YAML mode it insert indent when I type enter

before enter (| is cursor)

```
mc_autosave_progress:
  route: /@plac-budowy@/autozapis/{type}/{id}
  target: { controller: MyConstruction, process: autosave }
  requirements: { type: 'progress', id: \d+ }
  suffix: .json

mc_autosave:|
```

after

```
mc_autosave_progress:
  route: /@plac-budowy@/autozapis/{type}/{id}
  target: { controller: MyConstruction, process: autosave }
  requirements: { type: 'progress', id: \d+ }
  suffix: .json

  mc_autosave:
    |
```

I have the same behaviour when I use just newline.

Comment: Cannot reproduce... what is your version of yaml-mode?

Comment: @juanleon latest from github 0.0.9.

Comment: Same version; working fine.  Could you test with emacs -q (just eval your function and yaml-mode.el, then use `M-x yaml-mode` in one of your YAML files).  If problem is not reproduced, issue is in your init file.  If it is reproduced, problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @juanleon it seems that the problem was in my init file. I found it, it was `(electric-indent-mode +1)`

Answer (score 0):

> Test with emacs -q (just eval your function and yaml-mode.el, then use M-x yaml-mode in one of your YAML files).
>
> If problem is not reproduced, issue is in your init file. If it is reproduced, problem is elsewhere.
>
> It seems that the problem was in my init file. I found it, it was (electric-indent-mode +1)

Comment: Yes, I had electic-indent-mode, but what I want to is to disable it for yaml mode.